# How to Know Static Methods's Class Name

Tags: c#, reflection, methodbase

I have a class and it has some static methods. I have also another class inherits my first class like below;

```
public class Business
{
    public static DataTable Get()
    {
    }
}

public class Model : Business
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

I use it like below;

```
Model.Get();
```

Inside of Do method i try to catch type of Model class. I can catch Business class type like below inside of Do method;

```
public static DataTable Get()
{    
    Type t = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
}
```

But i can't catch the Model class type. How can i do that?

**Note :** Get method in Business class selects columns up to which class it is called from. This is why i need name of Model  class. Cause name of Model class will be name of table and it will select columns from table Model.

**Note 2 :** Normally i use it like;

```
Business.Get<Model>();
```

and i can get all data from Model table. But i try to use it like;

```
Model.Get();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. There is nothing called `B.Do()`. It implicitly means that `A.Do()`.

`Do` is a static method defined in `A`. There is no metadata of `B` exist in `Do` method as it's defined in `A`.

Being able to call `B.Do();` is just a convenience that C# compiler provides you. Note that resharper will warn you for this usage of base class member using a derived type.

Do note that even if you write

```
B.Do();
```

Compiler converts it to

```
call A.Do// Call IL
```

**Update:** As for the updated question, I recommend you to use instance methods as opposed to static methods.

```
Model model = new Model();
model.Get();
```

Inside of get you can use `GetType().Name` to get the class name of current instance.

```
public class Business
{
    public DataTable Get()
    {
         string className = this.GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a base class that does something up to from which class it is called. This is why i need name of B class. Cause name of B class will be name of table and it will select columns from table B

Comment: @thrashead I guess you need some sort of polymorphic behavior in getting the table name. Perhaps, update the question with more info about what you're trying to achieve, or ask a new question with all necessary information to answer the question. Thanks

Comment: I updated the question with a note. I try to develop a framework like entity framework and B class is a class has model members and it inherits A class to get it's methods. But i don't want to use virtual methods and override methods. Nothing will be overriden i need just type of table to catch members (properties) to make some functions like select, insert.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I can't offer much. I'd suggest to get rid of that static, let it be instance method in `A`. Then a virtual property say `TableName` which is overridden in `B` to return "B". Or attributes also can help. But you need to show us more code to be able to help.

Comment: Yes i use Generic Methods like B.Do<B>(); If i do like this i don't need to inherit A class. I can call it like A.Do<B>(); It also makes select and insert methods for table B. But it looks not nice you know. I try to use like B.Do(); instead of B.Do<B>(); or A.Do<B>();

Answer (score 0):

There is no method inheritance when it is going about `static` methods.
Calling `Do()` method in `B` class is allowed only for convenience, I believe. I suppose that your call `B.Do()` is compiled to `A.Do()` (because `B` class doesn't contain `Do()` method declaration). That is why your snippet returns `A`.

In order to make your method return `B` you should write:

```
public class A
{
    public static void Do()
    {
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public static void Do()
    {
    }
}
```